# Access Database with JSTL

Tags: sql, ms-access, jstl

Hi there im tryying to connect to a simple Access database with JSTL
I have a system DSN set up pointing to the data base called "book dB"

Every time try to open the site I get the error
Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Here's my code

```
<sql :setDataSource var="dataSource" 
  driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
  url="jdbc:odbc:book dB"   
/>

<sql:query var ="RS" >
  dataSource ="${dataSource}"
  SELECT * FROM Books
  WHERE BookTitle = 'Cooking for children'
</sql:query>
```

Id rather not use Access or JSTL, but they are required for a college assignment, but I just cant see what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Just a guess ... if your Java is 64 bit, you need the Access 64 bit ACE driver.

Comment: Your guess was correct, Java was running in 64 bit, while the access driver was 32bit. I have not gotten it working by setting up tomcat so it runs in 32bit java. I'll have to look up the access 64bit driver as that could come in handy and solve alot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem as HansUp said, by running tomcat in 32bit, to do so I had to change JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME Environmental variable's to point to a 32 bit install of Java Rather than the 64 bit version.

As the problem was due too the Access driver being 32 bit I'm sure the ACE Access Driver referred too would also have solved the problem and allowed me to continue to run Java in 64bit.